# Intellisense broken after installing CodeRush Devexpress

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, coderush

I've recently installed CodeRush Devexpress, and now VS intellisense doesn't appear whilst I'm typing.

Syntax highlighting also seems to be a little bit screwed, but my main worry is intellisense.

Any suggestions for getting Intellisense back without doing an uninstall of CodeRush?

### Update:

In the end, I uninstalled CodeRush, unchecked then rechecked some settings found [here](http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2007/06/09/Resharper-Breaks-Intellisense-After-Uninstall.aspx), and reverted the .csproj file of the project before the error occurred. Just re-installed and everything seems to be working now.

I'll submit this as a bug to their support later.

Comment: Have you installed any of the additional "Community plugins" for CodeRush? Or is this a clean CodeRush install. Also what version number and is it CodeRush Full or Xpress?

Comment: Reading the web site you indicated, it sounds like the problem wasn't so much installing CodeRush as it was the uninstall of resharper.

Comment: I havn't installed Resharper, it's just a site that I happened to find when googling the problem.

Comment: For anyone still searching and wanting simpler solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908420/uninstall-of-coderush-and-resharper-intellisense-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug.

I would raise a support issue at the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/sc/)

This provides you with a method for tracking the progress of said bug.

For the benefit of users of CodeRush Xpress, who might also come across this in the meantime, it should be noted that CodeRush Xpress is also fully supported by DevExpress even though it is free to you.

I further recommend that you post a link to the support issue here so that others who come across this bug can discover the outome.

Comment: Also worth perhaps seeing if this bug is tied to your current settings. Backup and then delete "%AppData%\CodeRush for .Net\Settings.XML\" (Assuming latest version 9.2.x or better) and See if the bug remains after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to [reset your settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28VS.80%29.aspx) by running

`Devenv /ResetSettings SettingsFile`

You can supply the `SettingsFile` parameter to restore to some previously saved settings, or you can omit the `SettingsFile` parameter and all default Visual Studio settings will be restored.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work again if you temporarily disable CodeRush, e.g. using the `/SafeMode` command line switch?

Answer (score 0):

In the interim, perhaps try a repair of the CodeRush Install.

Run up the installer again and choose **repair**.