# Uninstall of CodeRush and ReSharper - Intellisense Not Working

Tags: .net, resharper, intellisense, coderush

Install order:
Visual Studio 2008
ReSharper
Uninstall ReSharper
CodeRush with Refactor Pro
Uninstall CodeRush with Refactor Pro

Now my intellisense doesn't work. Any settings I should look at before I try a uninstall / reinstall? I'm sure there must be something buried in the Options that these plug-ins hook into or override.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here are a couple of settings to check:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > General > Statement completion

"Auto list members" and "Parameter information" should be checked.

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > General > IntelliSense

"Show completion list after a character is typed" and "Committed by pressing the space bar" should be checked.

Comment: Don't know how I missed this the first time through the settings. I think I was prompted by something in CodeRush and turned it off. Then uninstalling got me to this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

```
Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings
```

It sucks, but it's the only way I know of to restore intellisense after uninstalling Resharper.

Comment: thanks.  this fixed my issue which occurred the same day my Resharper trial period expired. Probably not a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks!! This solution fixed intellisense issue, which I got after uninstalling resharper!

Comment: It helps not to vary to far from vanilla Visual Studio.